# converting pasted numbers to vector of numbers in r

Tags: r, substring

I would like to convert the following string to separate values, including the minus sign

```
t <- "111111111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-11111-1-1-1-1-1111111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-111111-1-1-1-111111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-111111-1-1-1-1111111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1111-1-1-1-111111111"
```

to

```
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, etc)
```

any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stringr`'s `str_extract_all` function

```
as.integer(str_extract_all(t, '-?\\d')[[1]])
```

results

```
[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
[42]  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[83] -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

check

```
> nchar(t)
[1] 149
> nchar(str_replace_all(t, '\\d', ''))
[1] 49
> length(as.integer(str_extract_all(t, '-?\\d')[[1]]))
[1] 100
```

Comment: Similarly with `stringi` as in `library(stringi) ; as.integer(stri_extract_all(t, regex = '-?\\d')[[1]])`

Comment: Wilson, mrip and David: thank you soooo much for the fast answer. I definitely asked the right people!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strsplit`:

```
as.integer(strsplit(t, "(?<=\\d)", perl = TRUE)[[1]])
```

The result:

```
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 [26] -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
 [51]  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1
 [76]  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
as.integer(regmatches(t,gregexpr("\\d|-\\d",t))[[1]])
```